# Returning downloaded data from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, uikit, firebase-storage

I have a working function that downloads data from my Firebase Storage, but I don't understand how to actually use the data in my project.

```
func getImg2() {
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let imageRef = storageRef.child("images/hi2.png")
        
        _ = imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                
                print("Data: \(data!)")
                print("succesfully downloaded \(image!)")
            }
        }
    }
```

The data gets printed, as well as the image information. I would like to return this data and use it outside the function to load a UIImage. Everything I've tried has given me an error or just returned "0 bytes" for the data. I've been stuck on this for days and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Look up "completion handler" or "callback function"

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen can you please re-open my question? The post you suggested is not the same and does not answer my question.

Comment: You can't return something *now* that is asynchronously loaded, as it won't be available until *later*. You will need to pass in a callback function, that you call once the data is available. The questions I've linked show various ways to do that. --- If your problem is different than that, can you show us how it's different? For example, did you try implementing a callback function and did that not work? Can you show that?